# Paste image from clipboard into a acrobat form using javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, acrobat, acrobat-sdk

I'm setting up a form in Adobe Acrobat Standard DC to improve my workflow of one of my daily tasks. the form should contain a screenshot image of a window. I would love to click on a field and the before taken screenshot shows up automatically in there.

I found a method where I have to set up a "button" and attach a little javascript to it. the picture shows up as icon of the button. Sadly it opens up a window where I have to choose a file on the computer. Saving the picture before adding it to the form is very time consuming.

this is the little script i found:

JavaScript:

```
var s = this.getField("Picture")
s.buttonImportIcon();
```

I asked me if it's possible to change the buttonImportIcon to some "clipboardData.getData"-like funktion

Comment: In most web browsers, it is no longer possible to programmatically inspect the clipboard or programmatically paste the clipboard contents, due to information security issues

Comment: there is no web browser envolved. I just would use Adobe Acrobat Standard DC and attach the javascript to the button-properties - Action/run a javascript

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do so with code using Adobe Acrobat DC. You can, however, paste the image contents of the clipboard onto the document. It becomes a "stamp" annotation that you can then position and scale.